# AI surrounding algorithm suggestions

Tags: java, ai, movement

I am building up a simulation where predator groups (tribes) try to hunt other agents in the simulation (whom also are clustered in groups).

Now I got to a point where members of a group follow their leader and wait for any sort of commands (currently passed as strings and vector that they need to move towards).
Anyway the idea is to implement some interesting surrounding behaviour just like predators hunt in group they surround their prey.I shall attach a picture for better explanation:

[image]

The green circles are the agents that predators are hunting. The red circle is the leader of the predator group and the black dots are other predators. The sort of behaviours I am looking for should be similar to shown in the picture where on the right side of the picture the predators are surround the pack of green agents as instructed so by the leader of the predator pack.

What I was thinking initially was find the leftmost agent in the green pack and the right most in green agents pack and make members of the predator group move towards them.However at this point I shall mention that predators have a fixed field of view so it may not see all of the pack at first.

So I am wondering if anybody came across something like so or have any good ideas how to go about producing this sort of behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible method could be a draw an ellipse around the target pack and calculate the circumference.

divide the circumference by number in pack to evenly distribute.

create paths for units to move to their points.